# SQL Query Count number of games user has played

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am stuck on a problem at work but I will explain with a small example. I need to count the number of games each user has played but the game table is dynamic(more games can be added).

3 games are added to Games table:

[image]

```
DECLARE @Games AS TABLE
(
    Game_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) ,
    Description varchar(255) 
)
INSERT INTO @Games
VALUES ('FIFA 17'), ('FIFA 18'), ('FIFA 19')
```

There are 4 users:

[image]

```
DECLARE @Users AS TABLE
(
    Username varchar(255)
)
INSERT INTO @Users
VALUES ('UserA'), ('UserB'), ('UserC'), ('UserD')
```

The following table contains the information of what game each user has played and when:

[image]

```
DECLARE @Data AS TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) ,
    Username varchar(255) ,
    Game_ID INT ,
    Played_At DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO @Data
VALUES('UserA', 2, GETDATE()-1), ('UserA', 3, GETDATE()), ('UserA', 2, GETDATE()-3), ('UserB', 1, GETDATE()-5), ('UserB', 1, GETDATE()-1), ('UserB', 1, GETDATE()-1), ('UserC', 1, GETDATE()-1)
```

In the end scenario the information I am trying to get is how many Gamer_ID's appear against each user in information table. End scenario shown below:

[image]

The image above is my attempt on getting it working using the below code:

```
SELECT u.Username ,
       (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM @Data AS d WHERE d.Username = u.Username AND d.Game_ID = 1) AS [Game_ID_1] ,
       (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM @Data AS d WHERE d.Username = u.Username AND d.Game_ID = 2) AS [Game_ID_2] ,
       (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM @Data AS d WHERE d.Username = u.Username AND d.Game_ID = 3) AS [Game_ID_3]
FROM @Users AS u
```

However, this isn't a full solution as this needs to be more dynamic as more games can be added to games table. I can't keep changing the code. More Users can also be added but the above code does handle that at the moment. Is there a way to get it working dynamically so it can count new games added to the games table.

Full example code and attempt below:

```
DECLARE @Games AS TABLE
(
    Game_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) ,
    Description varchar(255) 
)
INSERT INTO @Games
VALUES ('FIFA 17'), ('FIFA 18'), ('FIFA 19')

DECLARE @Users AS TABLE
(
    Username varchar(255)
)
INSERT INTO @Users
VALUES ('UserA'), ('UserB'), ('UserC'), ('UserD')

DECLARE @Data AS TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) ,
    Username varchar(255) ,
    Game_ID INT ,
    Played_At DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO @Data
VALUES('UserA', 2, GETDATE()-1), ('UserA', 3, GETDATE()), ('UserA', 2, GETDATE()-3), ('UserB', 1, GETDATE()-5), ('UserB', 1, GETDATE()-1), ('UserB', 1, GETDATE()-1), ('UserC', 1, GETDATE()-1)

SELECT * FROM @Games
SELECT * FROM @Users
SELECT * FROM @Data

SELECT u.Username ,
       (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM @Data AS d WHERE d.Username = u.Username AND d.Game_ID = 1) AS [Game_ID_1] ,
       (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM @Data AS d WHERE d.Username = u.Username AND d.Game_ID = 2) AS [Game_ID_2] ,
       (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM @Data AS d WHERE d.Username = u.Username AND d.Game_ID = 3) AS [Game_ID_3]
FROM @Users AS u
```

SQL Server 2012

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please mention the version of your sql server.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Wanting a dynamic number of columns is a SQL Anti-Pattern. SQL is intended to be used with fixed numbers of columns using normalisation *(the language is set up specifically for it, and database engines are designed to expect it)*. In your case that is a column for the username, a column for the gameid and a column for the count. Then, as more games are added you get more rows rather than more columns. Fighting against this suggests you're either unfamiliar with normalised data structures, or that your trying to force presentation layer responsibilities into your data layer. ***Don't do it.***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare the hoops the dynamic pivot jumps through to the following code which generates a normalised structure.

```
SELECT
  username,
  game_id,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  @data
GROUP BY
  username,
  game_id
```

The reason this is shorter is that this is what SQL and database engines are designed and optimised ***for***.

The dynamic sql approach works, but is a huge code-smell. You're forcing a square peg in to a round hole. Don't do it, do things the way the technology was designed.

The code will run faster. The code will be shorter and more maintainable. The results will be reusable by later SQL. Etc, etc.

Comment: I forgot about group by. I used it so many times. I was over thinking the problem. Good solution and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic pivot to get your desired answer.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table games
 (
     Game_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
     Description varchar(255) 
 )
 INSERT INTO Games
 VALUES ('FIFA 17'), ('FIFA 18'), ('FIFA 19');
 
 create TABLE users
 (
     Username varchar(255)
 );
 INSERT INTO Users
 VALUES ('UserA'), ('UserB'), ('UserC'), ('UserD');
 
 create TABLE data
 (
     ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) ,
     Username varchar(255) ,
     Game_ID INT ,
     Played_At DATETIME
 );
 INSERT INTO Data
 VALUES('UserA', 2, GETDATE()-1), ('UserA', 3, GETDATE()), ('UserA', 2, GETDATE()-3), ('UserB', 1, GETDATE()-5), ('UserB', 1, GETDATE()-1), ('UserB', 1, GETDATE()-1), ('UserC', 1, GETDATE()-1);
```

Query:

```
  DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @colsForSelect AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
     
 SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(game_id) 
             FROM games 
             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
             ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
         ,1,1,'')
        
 
 SET @colsForSelect = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(game_id) +QUOTENAME(concat('Game_ID_',Game_ID))
             FROM games 
             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
             ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
         ,1,1,'')
        
 
 set @query = 'Select Username, ' + @colsForSelect + ' from 
             (
                  SELECT u.Username,game_id,count(*)g_id_count
 FROM Users AS u left join Data d on d.Username=u.Username
 group by u.Username,Game_ID
 
 
            ) x
             pivot 
             (
                  max(g_id_count)
                 for game_id in (' + @cols + ')
             ) p 
             group by username,' + @cols 
  
 execute(@query);
```

Output:

| Username | Game_ID_1 | Game_ID_2 | Game_ID_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UserA | null | 2 | 1 |
| UserB | 3 | null | null |
| UserC | 1 | null | null |
| UserD | null | null | null |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9ac4b82d8c27ec1122983071e941a874)*

Answer (score 0):

I've utilized your code and dynamic `T-SQL` along with the [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to accomplish this or `COALESCE` for older SQL Server Versions.

#### STRING_AGG Approach

See Demo Run from *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=45985b9ec4e10b01f236af97883eb73e)* below:

> ```
> select @@version;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU21) (KB4557397) - 14.0.3335.7 (X64) <br>        Jun 12 2020 20:39:00 <br>        Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation<br>        Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)<br> |
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Games
> (
>     Game_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) ,
>     Description varchar(255) 
> )
> INSERT INTO Games
> VALUES ('FIFA 17'), ('FIFA 18'), ('FIFA 19'), ('FIFA 20')
>
> CREATE TABLE Users
> (
>     Username varchar(255)
> )
> INSERT INTO Users
> VALUES ('UserA'), ('UserB'), ('UserC'), ('UserD')
>
> CREATE TABLE Data
> (
>     ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) ,
>     Username varchar(255) ,
>     Game_ID INT ,
>     Played_At DATETIME
> )
> INSERT INTO Data
> VALUES('UserA', 2, GETDATE()-1), ('UserA', 3, GETDATE()), ('UserA', 2, GETDATE()-3), ('UserB', 1, GETDATE()-5), ('UserB', 1, GETDATE()-1), ('UserB', 1, GETDATE()-1), ('UserC', 1, GETDATE()-1)
>
> SELECT * FROM Games
> SELECT * FROM Users
> SELECT * FROM Data
>
> SELECT u.Username ,
>        (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM Data AS d WHERE d.Username = u.Username AND d.Game_ID = 1) AS [Game_ID_1] ,
>        (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM Data AS d WHERE d.Username = u.Username AND d.Game_ID = 2) AS [Game_ID_2] ,
>        (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM Data AS d WHERE d.Username = u.Username AND d.Game_ID = 3) AS [Game_ID_3]
> FROM Users AS u
>
> SELECT 
>     Username, 
>     SUM(
>         CASE
>             WHEN Game_ID=1 THEN 1
>             ELSE 0
>         END
>     ) AS GAME_ID_1
> FROM
>     Data
> GROUP BY
>     Username
>
> DECLARE @tsqlGameTable NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT u.Username FROM Users AS u';
>
> IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 GAME_ID FROM Games  ) 
> BEGIN
>     
>     SELECT 
>         @tsqlGameTable = CONCAT(N'SELECT u.Username, (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM Data AS d WHERE d.Username = u.Username AND d.Game_ID = ',STRING_AGG(GAME_PIECE,N', (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM Data AS d WHERE d.Username = u.Username AND d.Game_ID = '),N' FROM Users AS u')
>     FROM (
>         SELECT
>             CONCAT(N' ',GAME_ID,') AS [Game_ID_',GAME_ID,'] ') AS GAME_PIECE
>         FROM
>             Games
>           
>     ) X
> END
> PRINT(@tsqlGameTable )
> -- SELECT @tsqlGameTable 
>
> EXECUTE(@tsqlGameTable )
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Game_ID | Description
> ------: | :----------
>       1 | FIFA 17    
>       2 | FIFA 18    
>       3 | FIFA 19    
>       4 | FIFA 20    
>
> | Username |
> | :------- |
> | UserA    |
> | UserB    |
> | UserC    |
> | UserD    |
>
> ID | Username | Game_ID | Played_At              
> -: | :------- | ------: | :----------------------
>  1 | UserA    |       2 | 2021-05-08 22:16:33.897
>  2 | UserA    |       3 | 2021-05-09 22:16:33.897
>  3 | UserA    |       2 | 2021-05-06 22:16:33.897
>  4 | UserB    |       1 | 2021-05-04 22:16:33.897
>  5 | UserB    |       1 | 2021-05-08 22:16:33.897
>  6 | UserB    |       1 | 2021-05-08 22:16:33.897
>  7 | UserC    |       1 | 2021-05-08 22:16:33.897
>
> Username | Game_ID_1 | Game_ID_2 | Game_ID_3
> :------- | --------: | --------: | --------:
> UserA    |         0 |         2 |         1
> UserB    |         3 |         0 |         0
> UserC    |         1 |         0 |         0
> UserD    |         0 |         0 |         0
>
> Username | GAME_ID_1
> :------- | --------:
> UserA    |         0
> UserB    |         3
> UserC    |         1
>
> Username | Game_ID_1 | Game_ID_2 | Game_ID_3 | Game_ID_4
> :------- | --------: | --------: | --------: | --------:
> UserA    |         0 |         2 |         1 |         0
> UserB    |         3 |         0 |         0 |         0
> UserC    |         1 |         0 |         0 |         0
> UserD    |         0 |         0 |         0 |         0
> ```

#### COALESCE APPROACH

> ```
> select @@version;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-CU-GDR) (KB4535288) - 12.0.6372.1 (X64) <br>        Dec 12 2019 15:14:11 <br>        Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation<br>        Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)<br> |
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Games
> (
>     Game_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) ,
>     Description varchar(255) 
> )
> INSERT INTO Games
> VALUES ('FIFA 17'), ('FIFA 18'), ('FIFA 19'), ('FIFA 20')
>
> CREATE TABLE Users
> (
>     Username varchar(255)
> )
> INSERT INTO Users
> VALUES ('UserA'), ('UserB'), ('UserC'), ('UserD')
>
> CREATE TABLE Data
> (
>     ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) ,
>     Username varchar(255) ,
>     Game_ID INT ,
>     Played_At DATETIME
> )
> INSERT INTO Data
> VALUES('UserA', 2, GETDATE()-1), ('UserA', 3, GETDATE()), ('UserA', 2, GETDATE()-3), ('UserB', 1, GETDATE()-5), ('UserB', 1, GETDATE()-1), ('UserB', 1, GETDATE()-1), ('UserC', 1, GETDATE()-1)
>
> SELECT * FROM Games
> SELECT * FROM Users
> SELECT * FROM Data
>
> SELECT u.Username ,
>        (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM Data AS d WHERE d.Username = u.Username AND d.Game_ID = 1) AS [Game_ID_1] ,
>        (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM Data AS d WHERE d.Username = u.Username AND d.Game_ID = 2) AS [Game_ID_2] ,
>        (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM Data AS d WHERE d.Username = u.Username AND d.Game_ID = 3) AS [Game_ID_3]
> FROM Users AS u
>
> SELECT 
>     Username, 
>     SUM(
>         CASE
>             WHEN Game_ID=1 THEN 1
>             ELSE 0
>         END
>     ) AS GAME_ID_1
> FROM
>     Data
> GROUP BY
>     Username
> DECLARE @gameColumns VARCHAR(MAX) -- (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM Data AS d WHERE d.Username = u.Username AND d.Game_ID = ' 
> DECLARE @tsqlGameTable NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT u.Username FROM Users AS u';
>
> IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 GAME_ID FROM Games  ) 
> BEGIN
>     SELECT
>          @gameColumns = COALESCE(@gameColumns + ', (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM Data AS d WHERE d.Username = u.Username AND d.Game_ID = ' + GAME_PIECE ,'')
>     FROM (
>         SELECT '' AS GAME_PIECE UNION ALL
>         SELECT
>             CONCAT(N' ',GAME_ID,') AS [Game_ID_',GAME_ID,'] ') AS GAME_PIECE
>         FROM
>             Games
>         
>          
>      ) X
>      
>      SET @tsqlGameTable = CONCAT(N'SELECT u.Username ', @gameColumns,' FROM Users AS u')
>   
> END
> -- PRINT(@tsqlGameTable)
> -- SELECT @tsqlGameTable 
>
> EXECUTE(@tsqlGameTable )
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Game_ID | Description
> ------: | :----------
>       1 | FIFA 17    
>       2 | FIFA 18    
>       3 | FIFA 19    
>       4 | FIFA 20    
>
> | Username |
> | :------- |
> | UserA    |
> | UserB    |
> | UserC    |
> | UserD    |
>
> ID | Username | Game_ID | Played_At              
> -: | :------- | ------: | :----------------------
>  1 | UserA    |       2 | 2021-05-09 02:21:35.083
>  2 | UserA    |       3 | 2021-05-10 02:21:35.083
>  3 | UserA    |       2 | 2021-05-07 02:21:35.083
>  4 | UserB    |       1 | 2021-05-05 02:21:35.083
>  5 | UserB    |       1 | 2021-05-09 02:21:35.083
>  6 | UserB    |       1 | 2021-05-09 02:21:35.083
>  7 | UserC    |       1 | 2021-05-09 02:21:35.083
>
> Username | Game_ID_1 | Game_ID_2 | Game_ID_3
> :------- | --------: | --------: | --------:
> UserA    |         0 |         2 |         1
> UserB    |         3 |         0 |         0
> UserC    |         1 |         0 |         0
> UserD    |         0 |         0 |         0
>
> Username | GAME_ID_1
> :------- | --------:
> UserA    |         0
> UserB    |         3
> UserC    |         1
>
> Username | Game_ID_1 | Game_ID_2 | Game_ID_3 | Game_ID_4
> :------- | --------: | --------: | --------: | --------:
> UserA    |         0 |         2 |         1 |         0
> UserB    |         3 |         0 |         0 |         0
> UserC    |         1 |         0 |         0 |         0
> UserD    |         0 |         0 |         0 |         0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=52fec4f49151ed44d5c91a4c6521a1b8)*